# Substring Comparision in Python while reading from File

Tags: python

I writing a python program to copy following lines ( around 10000) from one file to other. Condition is that if source register and destination register in lwz is same make that line bold and copy. Otherwise simply copy.

```
Line 850:   lwz     r3, 0(r17)
Line 851:   1004f0: 80 71 00 00     lwz r3,0(r17)
Line 1039:  lwz r5,0(r3)
Line 1040:   100598:    80 a3 00 00     lwz r5,0(r3)
Line 2029:     lwz     r9, 0(r4)               /* load half word from source */
Line 2030:   1009f8:    81 24 00 00     lwz r9,0(r4)
Line 2126:   100a5c:    81 3f 00 10     lwz r9,16(r31)
Line 2131:   100a68:    80 1f 00 10     lwz r0,16(r31)
```

I have written following program to copy lines from one file to other file.

```
import os
import sys
f1 = open('test.txt')
f2 = open('Output.txt', 'w')
str2 = "r9";
i=0
while i < 10:
     Lines=f1.readline()
     #Here I dont know
     f2.write(str(Lines))
     i=i+1;
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Can any one suggest how to convert Lines read from file into a string so that i can apply string operation on that. While I apply directly it gives error.

Comment: are you using Python 2 or Python 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the lines in your file:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f1:
    with open("Output.txt","w") as f2:
        for line in f1:
             dosomethingwith(line)
             f2.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Python3, and assuming your files are csv format and the `tabulator` symbol is the separator:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as left_file:
    with open('Output.txt', 'w',  encoding='utf-8') as right_file:

        for left_line, right_line in zip(left_file, right_file):
            left_cols = left_line.split('\t')
            right_cols = right_cols.split('\t')
            if left_cols[-1] == right_cols[-1]:
                # make text bold
                ...
```